# Multitail: two rows with two columns in bottom row

Tags: bash

I use Multitail for multiple log files I need to see on one terminal.

For three files, I have no problem to do this:

```
-----------------------
|                     |
-----------------------
|                     |
-----------------------
|                     |
-----------------------
```

Or this:

```
-----------------------
|           |         |
------------|         |
|           |         |
-----------------------
```

But unfortunately, what I want is this:

```
-----------------------
|                     |
-----------------------
|          |          |
-----------------------
```

In words, I want to split one row in two columns, while preserving the other row which should have only one column.

Comment: I would suggest - ask multitail author rather then here.

Comment: Well, you can also say that you don't know / the problem is not solvable using multitail / propose an alternative. That comment is kinda useless, but still I like the rhetorical

Comment: We can respond this to every questions.. With answer / comments like this , stack has no reason to exists !

Comment: We encourage questioners to show what they have tried so far to solve the problem themselves.

Comment: @Cyrus I think that is pretty clear in my question, what I have tried so far using Multitail (example one and example two). If not, please tell me how.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A possible workaround will be to use a tmux or terminator to split your screen with the good layout, then launch multitail inside each split

https://www.networkworld.com/article/3436784/how-to-use-terminator-on-linux-to-run-multiple-terminals-in-one-window.html?fbclid=IwAR19SkthhIo-GijfuRlrSSKQONtvxOHtpktx4m0L_2zRvsBo0UE65ra0560

Comment: That's a good idea, thanks!